# waypoints infinity scroll loads all pages at once

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm using `Waypoint infinity scroll` in my `Django template`.

```
<div class="infinite-container">
    {% for item in arbitrase_records %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 arbitrase-item">
            <!-- item content -->
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
{% endif %}
```

and the javascript goes like

```
<script src="{% static 'theme/js/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'theme/js/waypoints/lib/shortcuts/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      items: '.col-lg-3.arbitrase-item',
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.infinite-loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.infinite-loading').hide();
      },
      offset: -30
    });
</script>
```

for the first time, I scroll the page a little down, it loads all pages at once.

I have been trying different parameters to use with `offset`. setting `offset` to less than `30` like `-20` or `-10` stops the plugin to load any page.

**How can I make it load only next page and wait for further scroll?**

I also tried setting `'bottom-in-view'` in `offset` *(although, it is default)*. But then it loads all pages even without scrolling the page.